# AlertDialog disappears when touch is outside [Android]

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm using an Alert Dialog on my application, but it keeps hiding when the users touches outside it. 
Here is my code:

```
public class DialogMessageEnd extends DialogFragment
{
    String winner;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        Snooker_Scoreboard ss = new Snooker_Scoreboard();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setMessage(ss.winnerPlayer + " won the match ("+ss.frame1ToPass+"-"+ss.frame2ToPass+")!")
                .setPositiveButton("New Match!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getContext(),PlayerSelection.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });



        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

As you can see, I used

```
builder.setCancelable(false);
```

but it still doesn't solve the probem.
Can you help me? thanks

Comment: Did you take a look at `Dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside` method?

Comment: Selvin if you at least would read and understand, you would nothice that I am using Alert Dialog which does not have the setCanceledOnTouchOutside method.

Comment: @Pino AlertDialog does indeed have setCanceledOnTOuchOutside

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use **setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)** for preventing the dismiss on touching outside of alert dialog.

**setCancelable(false)** is used for preventing the dismiss on pressing the back button.

```
    @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    Snooker_Scoreboard ss = new Snooker_Scoreboard();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setMessage(ss.winnerPlayer + " won the match ("+ss.frame1ToPass+"-"+ss.frame2ToPass+")!")
            .setPositiveButton("New Match!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getContext(),PlayerSelection.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });



    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);         
    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: it tells me there's no setCanceledOnTouchOutside method for the AlertDialog.

Comment: see updated answer. refer two lines before the return statement

Comment: thanks man, that's perfect.

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.show();

alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

in your code

Answer (score 2):

You can override the default function for the Dialogue and assure nothing happens. Should work fine.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // If we've received a touch notification that the user has touched
    // outside the app, finish the activity.
    if (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE == event.getAction()) {
    // Do Something or not...
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or for better practice:

```
builder.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
```